# Jsoup clean method leaves &nbsp; elements

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I was trying using this code to clean my text entirely from HTML elements:

```
Jsoup.clean(preparedText, Whitelist.none())
```

Unfortunately it didn't remove the `&nbsp;` elements. I thought that it will replace it with a whitespace, the same way as it replace the `&middot;` with a middle dot ("·").

Should I use another method in order to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Why don't you replace it using `replace` method?

Comment: @MarounMaroun, replace method will work, but I wonder why Whitelist.none() didn't handle it.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Jsoup docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html):

> Whitelists define what HTML (elements and attributes) to allow through
>   the cleaner. Everything else is removed.

So the whitelist are concerned only with tags and attributes. `&nbsp;` is neither a tag nor an attribute. It is simply the html encoding for a special character. If you want to translate from the encoding to normal text you may use for example the excellent [apache commons lang library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String)) or use the [Jsoup unescapeEntities method](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#unescapeEntities-java.lang.String-boolean-):

```
System.out.println(Parser.unescapeEntities(doc.toString(), false));
```

**Addendum:**

The translation from `&middot;` to "·" already happens when you parse the html. It does not seem to have to do with the clean method.

Comment: That's correct, but what I'm trying to understand is why there is a difference between &middot; and &nbsp; in the way Jsoup handle these elements (in its clean method).

Comment: Indeed this is strange. Maybe you should raise an issue on the JSOUP project's github https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues